# Decompile APK and import in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, decompiling

I Decompile apk with online tool "http://www.decompileandroid.com/" and with "APK studio".

Decompiling is okay, with all .java files, images and xml files.
But i want to import this in android studio, as normal project.

When i select decomplied project in android studio, it just show project name,  no src files, no XML files, no images..

Comment: I  believe you have to set your project structure manually after decompile

Comment: Did you resolve/manage to compile back to apk ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also use **apktool** to decompile and recompile the APK. Use the following steps to decompile

```
apktool d <apk>
```

and to compile back

```
apktool b <apk>
```

When your APK is decompiled, it is not in the exact source code form. You will see a lot of dex hooks and in general it is not an exact android project that an IDE can recognise and import. You can use any normal editor to read the code and understand to make changes.

Download link: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: @ I dont see any java file. There are files of .smali extension.

Comment: apktool doesn't decompile to java.  it decompiles to smali, which is essentially assembly language for the dalvik interpreter.  You can recompile it (with apktool) and there is a plugin for android studio to work with it, but it isn't java.

Comment: apktool 2.7.0 works fine for small apks, but when I decode one bigger apk (multiple dex files), the encoded version can not find some symbols.I do not change anything but symbol looks like lost.