# Unlock APK files in Android Studio for editing

Tags: android, mobile, apk

Newbie here!

I have downloaded the .apk to Android Studio to make some changes to the code. I want to add a requirement for a user to insert 'a memorable word' when they register. But when I try and edit the required file, I just get an alert box telling the file is read only. I have tried to alter this in the panel but to no effect. It is possible the previous developer locked the files. How do I go about editing from this point forward, if the developer has locked the files, on which file/folder do I alter to make the files editable.

Answer (score 2):

The .apk file you have is a compiled version of the code. Android studio can decompile this for you when you import it to view the content, but you cannot edit the decompiled code directly.

Your best bet is to acquire the original source code. Other option is to try decompiling and recompiling the .apk like explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298815/decompile-apk-and-import-in-android-studio).